# Bind List<T> to Grid View

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, list, gridview

I have a list of strings which stores information about a specified movie.
Each item in the list corresponds to a piece of information about the movie e.g title, duration, description etc.

How would I bind this list to a gridview so that each item is on it's own column but within the same row?

I have used gridview.datasource = list but this simply adds each item of the list to the gridview as a separate row. I need the entire list to be in the same row but in separate columns of that row.

Below is the image of what happens when I simply just bind the list as the gridview datasource.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to show as per row record, could you build a `List<Movie>`? 
where

```
class Movie {
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public string Category {get; set;}
    public string Studios {get; set;}
}
```

if you do

```
List<Movie> list = GetData();
gridview.datasource = list;
```

you will get what you want. But if you only have one record, does it has sense to use a GridView?

Comment: What would "GetData()" refer to?

Comment: whatever method where you retrieve your data: from a database, for example

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `GridView`.  A `GridView` is specifically designed to represent a table of information where each bound item is one row.  To bind some data to a different UI representation use the general case `Repeater` where you can specify a template for each bound item to be whatever you want, rather than the special case of it being a row in a table.